# Issue deleting entire series from custom Event list

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I'm working with a custom Event list in our SharePoint 2010 site; the list is of calendar events, with a couple extra date/time columns and a little extra information.

I have a Web Part working that can create new items (both individual and recurring), and I can select, edit, and delete individual occurrences of a recurring series.  However, when I delete the series, the exceptions (edits and deletes) of the series are left behind.

This issue only appears when creating the recurring list item programmatically.  If I create a new recurring item from the Calendar view, I can edit a single occurrence, then when I delete the series, the edits are also removed from the list.

To try to track down the issue myself, I created another web part that lets me compare field values side-by-side for list items.  I created a recurring series through the Calendar view, and another with the same start/end/recurrence programmatically.  All of the defining fields look identical (`EventDate` date/time, `EndDate` date/time, `RecurrenceData`, `TimeZone`, `XMLTZone`, `fAllDayEvent`, `fRecurrence`).

When I compare edited occurrences, the following field values look the same for occurrences edited in Calendar view and programmatically: `EventDate`, `EndDate`, `RecurrenceID`, `fAllDayEvent`, `fReccurrence`, `ReccurrenceData`, `TimeZone`.  I also verified that the `MasterSeriesItemID` is set correctly.

Not sure what I'm missing, but I'm wondering if it has something to do with some of our custom fields, is that possible?  I set up a test project that works against a simple calendar list, and with that project I can programmatically delete a recurring series, and all exceptions in the series that I create in the test web part are automatically removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that I wasn't explicitly setting the `All Day Event` field in the exception item.  I went back and compared line by line the code in my working test project with my non-working web part, and saw that the line was missing where I set the `All Day Event` field to true.  I didn't catch it before because the field value was always set to Yes/true.

By adding the line that explicitly sets that field, exception items are now correctly deleted when I delete the entire series.